# Lookup Field order

Tags: sharepoint, lookup

I have a lookup field for a list of GMT time zones and I would like to define the order that the items appear on the new item and update item forms so that I can show on the dropdown box:

```
GMT +1
GMT +2
GMT +3
```

instead of

```
GMT +1
GMT +10
GMT +11
GMT +12
GMT +3
```

As much as I know, the lookup fields order the items alphabetically, is there a way to modify this order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom lookup field that allows to choose a list view to load data from (e.g. [SharePoint Filtered Lookup Field](http://filteredlookup.codeplex.com/)) and sort data in the view appropriately.

I cannot test it, since I don't have access to SharePoint at the moment, but adding a space for 1-digit timezones might do the trick to:

```
GMT  +1
GMT  +2
GMT  +3
...
GMT +10
GMT +11
```

If that doesn't work, consider:

```
GMT +01
GMT +02
GMT +03
...
GMT +10
GMT +11
```

Comment: I'll try the custom lookup field because the other 2 solutions change the presentation of the field and I want to avoid those kind of solutions. 

Thanks for the answer!